# Robotium Solo - wait for broadcast

Tags: android, robotium

I want to create a condition to wait for a broadcast upon a button press
right now I am just doing `solo.sleep(10000)`
but I dont want to sleep solo for nothing

How do I formulate the condition `"broadcast received"` ?

Ok explanations
Robotium Solo is an instrumentation framework with nice api

It has a method called "solo.waitForCondition(Condition, int timeout)"

I want to formulate (the word formulate means say what i want to say in correct words)

the correct condition that will tell me that the broadcast was indeed received
I want to write some code (I don't know which exactly) to know that the broadcast was indeed sent

for example, **if i want to know that a button is now visible** i would write

```
solo.waitForCondition(new Condition(){

public boolean isSatisfied(){

Button b = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myButton);
return b.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}

}
```

now back to my question - What (not how, but what) do I write in order to know for sure that the broadcast was sent inside the isSatisfied method

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't your broadcast listener only get triggered when there is a broadcast? Instead of sleep you'll want a while loop that only stops when a cancel button is pressed or a broadcast is received, since sleep also prevents you from receiving broadcasts.

Comment: I sleep solo, not the threads , if i debug the app i see the broadcast is received and acted upon, in my test i registered a broadcast receiver for the given intent, but i want to know that my test broadcast receiver was called as well (meaning the intent was sent) so how do i write 

solo.waitForCondition("broadcast received",30 );

Comment: I think we might need to see some code for this, but as I understand it you're correctly receiving a broadcast in your app and you also want to pass it to the test receiver? It sounds to me like it would be desirable to change the method so you can pass in a listener from both test and real code depending on what you're running.

Comment: @G_V please read my edits

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant that you don't want to sleep for 10 seconds, if you get the broadcast earlier. What you can do is

```
long beginTime = new Date().getTime();
while (new Date().getTime() - beginTime  < 10000) {
    solo.sleep(500);
    if (conditionMet) {
        // Do something
        break;
    }
}
```

This way you can do these checks on smaller intervals.

Ok, so in fact this is more or less how waitForCondition is implemented. Unfortunately I don't think you can listen for events with robotium. What you can do is monitor the view hierarchy. In your case, there should be some difference to the views that is triggered when the button is clicked, so that is what you need to check for in the Condition (and your example does that).

This is if you don't want to edit the code you are testing. If you are willing to change the code, you can add an onClickListener() and in that you can set a view's Tag to a boolean for example. Later in robotium you can check for that tag for being set. This is however not good way to do it, because you are adding more code just for the sake of the tests.

Comment: this is not what i meant ;)
I meant what do i write in order to have "conditionMet" = true